# In Django, How do you write the url pattern for a json file?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

My website generates json files in saves them with the user specified name: `test.json`

I couldn't immediately access it, so I assumed that I would have to write a URL pattern and view to see this file.

I want something akin to this :

```
url(r'^(?P<Controller>).json$', views.loadjson, name='loadjson')
```

Comment: Are you storing these files in the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serve static JSON files then doing so through Django is not the best way - if that's the case use something like Nginx.

If you wan't Django to generate those files and/or for e.g. an authentication mechanism in front of it then ok for Django.

To your question:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^(?P<json_file>[\w]+).json$', views.loadjson, name='loadjson')
```

It seems like you forgotten about `[\w]+` which I guess is the right pattern for your needs.
the view function will be called with a WSGIRequest instance and the `json_file` argument (from your url pattern), from there you should be able to do whatever you like with the file. It's a good idea to return in as an `application/json` content type as those are supposed to be JSON.

```
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def loadjson(request, json_file):
    # open, generate, fetch the json file
    # for e.g.:
    json_content = read_file(json_file)
    return HttpResponse(
        json_content,
        content_type='application/json',
        status=200
    )
```